# SharePoint Online list view

Tags: list, iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a standard list on SPO using standard modern view. What I want to to is to make the list look like it is not part of Office365 but just a container that holds data. This data should then be embedded and displayed on an external page (outside of Office365). Authentication using SSO from this external page to Office365 is no problem here (OpenID Connect).

Option 1: remove navigation bar, sharing button, Office365 bar at the very top,logo... remove everything but the list containing my data. Only this list must be affected, not other lists on this site collection. Link to this view looks like this: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx

Option 2: Embed the list on the external page (iframe?) - if this is even possbile?

Is there any other option and if not, could I use Option 1 or 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@ReyamOki,

It's not possible to embed SP online page into an iframe, it will trigger error.

SP modern UI provided a speed mode, does it meet the requirement?

[image]

The url is :

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/Lists/mm/AllItems.aspx?env=WebView
```

BR